# Calculate the limit of $\lim _{n \to \infty} (1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^n $

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the limit of

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} (1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^n $$

I know that it should be $e^{-1} $ because of 
$\lim _{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{k}{n})^n = e^k $ but how can I show that the $+1$ downstairs doesn’t change that. Intuitively speaking it's clear, but how can I show it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: it is $$\left(\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$

Comment: This is a very straightforward and nice way. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that $$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^n=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}$$ and now apply the product rule for limits. We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=e^{-1}$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}=1$$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}=e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

For any finite $k$, we have

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^{n}$$
$$ = \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^{n+k}}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k}$$
$$ = \frac{\lim _{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^{n+k}}{\lim _{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+k}\right)^k}$$

$$ = \frac{e^{-1}}{1}$$
$$ = \boxed{\frac{1}{e}}$$

The limit of the denominator is obviously $1$ in the fraction above. For a rigorous proof use Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: The limit is $1/e$.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Had it in my mind when I started out but got distracted.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that as follows:

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\overset{*}{=}\\
=&\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{e}
\end{align*}$$

*This equality holds, since the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ **does exist** and is equal to $e$.

Generally, when you don't know how to compute a limit, brute-force may work! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
(1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^n
=\frac{(1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}}{(1 - \frac{1}{n+1})}\to {1/e}
$$
since the denominator tends to $1$.